# Building an Angular Dashboard from a config.json

Tags: angular

I have an angular application using a library that I built.
Now I want to create a dashboard which gets configured by using a config.json file.

The config.json should look like this:

```
"dashboardElements":
   [
    {
        "selector": "lib-events-list",  // the components are within a library
        "colspan": 2,                   // config values for the dashboard
        "input_params": {
            "eventId": "12345",
            "eventName": "Testevent"    // input parameters for the angular components shown within the dashboard
         }
    },
    {
        "selector": "lib-visitors-list",
        "colspan": 2,
        "input_params": {
            "visitorId": "68865",
            "visitorName": "MaxMustermann"
        }
    }
   ]
```

The selectors are from my library and the unput parameters are inputs for those components.
I.e. the lib-events-list component within my library looks like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'lib-events-list',
    templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() eventId: string;
  @Input() eventName: string;
  ...
}
```

So my question is: Is this even possible with angular? How do I create my components within that dashboard? How do I create the routing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the least problematic approach would be creating switch that for selector value chooses what component to draw and do loop over all configs from your dashboard configuration but there are some more advanced techniques that can be used for this maybe someone will have time to write one of them down below

Answer (score 1):

The least problematic approach would be creating switch that for selector value chooses what component to draw and do loop over all configs from your dashboard.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of config">
  <div [ngSwitch]="item.selector">
    <lib-events-list *ngSwitchCase="'lib-events-list'" [eventId]="item.input_params.eventId" [eventName]="item.input_params.eventName"></lib-events-list>
    <some-other-component *ngSwitchCase="'some-other-component'"></some-other-component>
    ... and even more for each special component you can use

  </div>
</div>
```

[Example of simple solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-dashboard)

I want to note here that that you could want to create some dynamic components to handle such use case but this solution is simpler to implement for small amount of components.

[Dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. This sounds great, but I'd prefer if the dashboard doesn't have to know about the components and its input parameters. I will have a look into dynamic components first.

Comment: at least the part about not knowing about components input you can solve by having some standard input interface which for example always takes one input as a configuration object. If you manage to do this with dynamic components please post your solution as I would like to learn how to that correctly as last time I tried I had some issues with component lifecycles (i tried it in angular 4 maybe it easier now).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the data from this json, for your dashboard and the key is the selector, right.

Comment: Right. The selector is the selector of the component within my library and I want to display that component within the dashboard by using the input_params of the config as the @Input parameters of the components.

Comment: In this json how many different selectors you can have and how many different fields can a input_params have

Comment: I don't know yet how many those could be as the library is still beeing built. Currently about maybe 10 different selectors. But it will be more in the future.